# Can anyone please tell me why I am getting an error of ora-00904?

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT 
    C.C_CODE, I.INV_NUM, I.INV_DATE, P.DESCRIPT, L.L_UNITS, L.L_PRICE
FROM 
    CUSTOMER C 
JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM INVOICE I
     JOIN 
         (SELECT * 
          FROM LINE L
          JOIN (SELECT * FROM PRODUCT) P ON P.P_CODE = L.P_CODE) LP ON I.INV_NUM = LP.INV_NUM
          ORDER BY I.INV_NUM DESC) ILP ON C.C_CODE = ILP.C_CODE
ORDER BY 
    C.C_CODE;
```

This is the error I get:

> ORA-00904: "L"."L_PRICE": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier

Comment: have you thought about indenting the select statement to make it a little more readable

Comment: sorry i am new to stack overflow didn't knew how to edit

Answer (score 1):

You have redifined the table name so the table L  is not more available at the upper select level 
You should use the correct (last) (ILP) table name you have assigned  to the select related  to the column L_PRICE

or you don't have a L_PRICE column in your tables

```
    SELECT 
        C.C_CODE, I.INV_NUM, I.INV_DATE, P.DESCRIPT, L.L_UNITS, L.L_PRICE
    FROM 
        CUSTOMER C 
    JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
             FROM INVOICE I
             JOIN 
                    (SELECT * 
                      FROM LINE L
                      JOIN (SELECT * FROM PRODUCT) P ON P.P_CODE = L.P_CODE
                    ) LP ON I.INV_NUM = LP.INV_NUM
                  ORDER BY I.INV_NUM DESC
        ) ILP ON C.C_CODE = ILP.C_CODE
    ORDER BY 
        C.C_CODE;
```

Comment: @P_S   . you have renamed   (by the JOIN) the original table so you  must use this renamed  table name for identify the column .. looking to your code  this seems is ILP but have renamed  several times the table .. (could be you need  explict column too)

Answer (score 0):

The table alias `L` only has scope *within* the subquery.

Your subquery has the alias `ILP`; use that:

```
SELECT ..., ILP.L_STATUS
```